# How to type in telerik textbox in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, telerik

I am automating an application where I want to type a text in textbox with xpath like //input[@id='some id'] but while there is a class attribute after input which is changing dynamically due to which I am not able to type the text.
Is there any way so that I can include the dynamic attribute in my xpath and type the text?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue at one point. I never did find a resolution to it, so I ended up disabling the dynamic input settings for the test site via a web config entry. Definitely not ideal, but it at least allowed testing to continue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                                              I am going to automate the whole application so I don't think disabling dynamic settings is a good idea as I need to do this each time when I am running the test suite. I searched about telerik textbox selection through selenium but haven't got any success.Does selenium support telerik controls? or is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: I searched for some more time I finally got solution for this here.... http://www.msigman.com/2012/02/entering-radnumerictextbox-selenium-webdriver-1-6-0/

Comment: Interesting, I tried a few similar workarounds previously, but didn't have any luck with my application (We bind a list to the text box to support an intellisense type function, so it's a little different).